# What type of variable stores Boolean values?

Tags: conditionals, expl3, latex3

Does LaTeX3 (specifically, `expl3`) support variables of type Boolean? If not, variables of what type (a token? a token list? a string?) should I use to store Boolean values (i.e. `\c_true_bool` and `\c_false_bool`)?

Comment: `\bool_set_true:N \l_evan_foo_bool` seems like saying that `\l_evan_foo_bool` is a variable that stores a Boolean value, doesn't it?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `bool` type seems what you're looking for:

```
\bool_new:N \l_evan_foo_bool

\bool_set_true:N \l_evan_foo_bool
\bool_set_false:N \l_evan_foo_bool
```

How ‘true’ and ‘false’ are implemented internally should be of no concern. In particular, Boolean variables *cannot* be used directly in arithmetical computations, but you can use

```
\bool_if:NTF \l_evan_foo_bool { 1 } { 0 }
```

inside arithmetical expressions in order to emulate languages where 1 is true and 0 is false.